# d3 zoom and pan with hover functions

Tags: d3.js

I have a graph that has zoom and pan from this example code: (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172). My graph is almost exactly like that one, except with different data points, and circles noting each data point.

Now I'm trying to allow for a mouseover function that will display the data for each data point when hovering. However, the zoom behavior is taking precedence, and I'm not sure how to switch the behaviors so that the zoom is listening and the mouseover/hover happens (first, maybe?).

I'm trying to use this code sample since it has both the hover and zoom behaviors: (https://bl.ocks.org/lorenzopub/013c0c41f9ffab4d27f860127f79c5f5)

Comment: Can you share the code you have - how have you combined the two examples?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
d3.select("#rect").style("pointer-events", "all")
```

Have solved my problem.
I think the mouse events where not propagated properly.